# Calculate duration between momentjs timestamps in UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, duration

I am having a hard time to calculate the duration (difference in time) of two timestamps.
There is a timestamp I receive from the server in the following format:

`start # => "2017-05-31 06:30:10 UTC"`
(This is basically rubys `DateTime.now.utc`)

I want to see how many hours have passed since then until as of right now.
The calculation happens in the angularjs frontend only.
I tried the following:

```
var start = moment("2017-05-31 06:30:10 UTC", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z").utc();
var now = moment.utc();
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(start));
console.log(duration.asHours()); #=> 2 hours even though the point in time was just a couple of minutes ago.
```

Unfortunately this would always use my devices local time and produce a time that's a few hours off the actual time.

So my approach was to either convert all times to UTC and let momentjs handle all this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is UTC you can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) method.

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

Here a live example:

```js
var start = moment.utc("2017-05-31 06:30:10 UTC", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z");
var now = moment.utc();
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(start));
console.log(duration.asHours());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In your code sample, you are parsing the input string as local date and then converting it to UTC (with [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) method).

See [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide to get more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I understood the documentation you quoted as "optionally, you might as well write it this way". Apparently I was wrong there ;p