# Calculate duration from timestamps in one column SQL postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database in Postgres SQL with information on users browsing online content. I would like to calculate the duration of browsing for each browsing episode (episode is one start and one stop action for the same Action_ID) and then to see it per user and per day. 
I can identify users by User_ID and by Action column to see when browsing started and ended.

I am therefore stuck with figuring out how to instead of having two rows per Action (with start and stop time) make one row per browsing Action with duration time only?

```
Date_time       User_ID Device_ID   Action  Action_ID  Channel_ID
22/07/2016 00:10    id2  pc      stop   123qwe      gn3
22/07/2016 00:10    id5  pc      start  345ert      tm6
22/07/2016 00:10    id1  mob     stop   567rfg      uy6
22/07/2016 00:12    id1  mob     start  567rfg      uy6
22/07/2016 00:13    d3   pc      stop   987yhn      io9
```

I've tried [Calculate duration between momentjs timestamps in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277682/calculate-duration-between-momentjs-timestamps-in-utc) and [Calculate duration between timestamps in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319885/calculate-duration-between-timestamps-in-one-column) already and I've done some googling, but I didn't get any closer.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the logic for defining "browsing episode".

Comment: browsing episode would be the time between 'start' and 'stop' for the same Action_ID

Comment: @GordonLinoff just edited, it should be there now

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dates as:

```
select date_trunc('day', date_time) as theday, user_id, action_id,
       min(date_time) filter (where action = 'start') as start_time,
       max(date_time) filter (where action = 'stop') as stop_time
from t
group by theday, user_id, action_id;
```

The duration is then the difference between these -- but the exactly logic depends on how you want to see the duration.

Comment: I tried this solution and it gave me an Error: "function date_trunc(unknown, character varying) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types."  I thought this is caused because of the 'date_time' column data type and I tried changing it to timestamp with CAST. This didn't work - is that because there are no seconds in the 'date_time' column?

Comment: Fix your data so the date is stored as a *datetime* and not a string.  `date_trunc()` works fine in Postgres.  You could try `'day'::text` *after* fixing the column type.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I fixed the datatype and I split my data into 2 separated columns instead : one with date and one with time. Thus, the above solution is not calculating the desired output of duration time of action from start to stop in minutes.